# Text not aligned properly (ZCAnimatedLabel)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using ZCAnimatedLAbel Library on github.
https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel

But my text is not properly aligned.
[image]

See letter "E" is starting before the the text bound.

Please help me with this.
For reference, code to for text is in ZCCoreTextLayout file

Comment: It could be an issue with the font used.

Comment: which font are you using?